# Нужна помощь по подбору JS библиотеки

Tags: javascript, highcharts, chart.js, google-chart

Как красиво расположить и, по возможности, добавлять и редактировать блоки организующей схемы компании с использованием Ajax?

Cхема может состоять, например, из следующих орг. единиц:

```
+----+--------------------+------+--------+-------+
| id | name               | sub  | parent | level |
+----+--------------------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Board of directors | NULL |   NULL |     0 |
|  2 | D1                 |    1 |      1 |  NULL |
|  3 | D2                 |    1 |      1 |  NULL |
|  4 | D3                 |    1 |      1 |  NULL |
|  5 | CEO                | NULL |      1 |     1 |
|  6 | CFO                | NULL |      5 |     2 |
|  7 | CTO                | NULL |      5 |     2 |
|  8 | Department 1       | NULL |      1 |     3 |
|  9 | Department 2       | NULL |      6 |     3 |
| 10 | Department 3       | NULL |      6 |     3 |
| 11 | Department 4       | NULL |      7 |     3 |
| 12 | Department 5       | NULL |      7 |     3 |
+----+--------------------+------+--------+-------+
```

В результате, при обработке полученного XML/JSON, должна отобразиться приблизительно такая структура:

[image: оргсхема]

Меня интересует только инструмент, который максимально подойдет для решения подобной задачи. Прошу обратить внимание, что важно учитывать расположение блоков по вертикали (level), а также вложенные блоки.

Comment: Вопрос нужный и полезный, буду следить за ответами, так как и сам ищу :)